# Header Text formating

Tags: magento2

I am not a developer, but working on my own web site. I would like to increase the number of text formats ( header Texts ) in Magento 2.2. Can anyone assist with the following.

Can this be done and what file would need to be altered and with what code

Comment: Increase the number of text formats means increase font size ?